# Using jQuery to dynamically display an overlay element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to use jQuery to dynamically display a 'Pin this' button on top of my images. The problem is, when the button shows, it pushes the actual image over. Here's the live view:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rGAzy

The problem is fixed by changing the position to absolute, but by doing so, it'll bring the button all the way to the top. One of the pages I wanted to test on is http://fstoppers.com/500px-announces-a-new-portfolio-system-and-new-prices

I inherited the theme from someone else, so if I change the  to having absolute position, it'll on the entire site.

Am I approaching this problem all wrong? How do I go about having a dynamic button?

Answer (score 0):

Make it absolute, indeed, but add `position: relative;` to the parent `p` tag.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gvKzE

Answer (score 0):

This is best solution, without extra Javascript, just change your html structure:

```
<div id="container" style="position: relative;">
    <img />
    <div class="pin-button" style="position: absolute;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Same as the other solution. This fix moved all the images up in one place and the CSS practically broke across the board :(

Comment: @aZn137 did you change the HTML structure? because if absolute is in relative, it won't float in relatives container...